# Error with Google Play Service Client

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've been working on trying to get this android project to work in android studio with gradle. I'm fairly new to it all so it may be a simple issue but I have spent quite a few days and cannot get past this error I receive when trying to run my project:

```
Error:(25, 62) error: package com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist
Error:(26, 62) error: package com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist
Error:(27, 39) error: cannot find symbol class LocationClient
Error:(42, 60) error: cannot find symbol class ConnectionCallbacks
Error:(43, 3) error: cannot find symbol class OnConnectionFailedListener
Error:(82, 10) error: cannot find symbol class LocationClient
Error:(586, 26) error: cannot find symbol class LocationClient
Error:(618, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(627, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(635, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is the top portion of the file the errors are coming from (i've marked troubled lines):

```
package edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.***GooglePlayServicesClient***.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.***GooglePlayServicesClient***.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.***location.LocationClient***;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class FragmentMainInput extends Fragment implements **ConnectionCallbacks**,
        **OnConnectionFailedListener**, LocationListener,
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    Intent fi;
    TripData trip;
    NoteData note;
    boolean isRecording = false;
    Timer timer;
    float curDistance;

    TextView txtDuration;
    TextView txtDistance;
    TextView txtCurSpeed;

    int zoomFlag = 1;

    Location currentLocation = new Location("");

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    // Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable mUpdateTimer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateTimer();
        }
    };

    private final static int MENU_USER_INFO = 0;
    private final static int MENU_HELP = 1;

    private final static int CONTEXT_RETRY = 0;
    private final static int CONTEXT_DELETE = 1;

    DbAdapter mDb;
    GoogleMap map;
    UiSettings mUiSettings;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;

    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000) // 5 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16) // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    public FragmentMainInput() {
    }
```

When I hover the lines flagged in the code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
```

It says:"cannot resolve symbol"

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }

            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they
// belong in the individual module build.gradle files
            }
        }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

And also here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.TabsConfig"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.MainInputActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_input" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.TripPurposeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trip_purpose" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.UserInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.TripMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trip_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.SavedTripsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_saved_trips" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.TripDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trip_detail" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.NoteTypeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_note_type" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.NoteDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_note_detail" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.NoteMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_note_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.SavedNotesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_saved_notes" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.RecordingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.ppl.cycleatlanta.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB9orX8RcKrVvF8Vg1_yMhIvu59XUW_inw" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It seems to me there is a problem with the google play service linking. I've followed several different examples and definitely have it downloaded but I cant get it to work. Also I have a feeling my manifest (nout sure about the correct targets for sdk version) and gradle file (jcenter or maven?and setting proper dependencies)  may be configured improperly.

Any help with this would be great I've spent the last few days scouring the interwebs but I have not been able to solve what Im sure is a simple issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your location implementation is based on an older version of Google Play services but you imported Play services 7.0.0 that "GooglePlayServicesClient" is no longer exist.

You can change play services version to an older version in your build.gradle file
or
You can use [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample) sample for newer location implementation.

Comment: Hey thanks. Check my response below as I just discovered lowering the play service version appears to be key. Can you tell me how to determine the correct play service version to use?

Comment: I don't know in which version GoogleApiClient introduced. Test different versions that is listed in your sdk path: extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Google Play Services 7.0.0 you just need to change

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
```

to

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
```

you also should remove onDisconnected method if you overrided it.

Answer (score 4):

So interesting enough I continued to lurk moar and discovered someone suggested this foe the dependencies in the gradle build:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
```

Not sure what cardview is or recyclerview but the play services is a considerable lower version. But the damn thing builds! Only problem now is the app crashes in the emulator (unfortunately it has stopped message) as soon as you try to open it. I wonder if it is a new problem or perhaps my configuration is still off?

Comment: For emulator crash problem, download Google APIs emulator system image that contains Play services apk form sdk manager and create new AVD.